# Securing a Node js application within Azure app services using Active Directory Authentication

Tags: node.js, azure

I am hosting a Node Js application on Azure App services and followed the article here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs

The app works fine and one can browse to the hello world page printed by index.js.

However, I have attempted to apply authentication to this app using Azure Active Directory Express and I always receive the error: "app is currently unable to handle this request" after signing in and being redirected.

My question would be, am I missing a step? I have literally set up the Azure Active Directory Express authentication and have not changed any of the code from the node js quick start article. Do I also need to incorporate additional code within the index.js file as well to handle the authentication?

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I test it both with linux and windows app, both worked. Did you follow this doc to configure the AAD auth? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings

Comment: Hi Joy, I did indeed. Our company uses Okta and SSO and the redirect back to the site essentially fails after login. Any ideas? Thanks